# SOCKJS reply upon SOCKET_CREATED event

Tags: javascript, vert.x, sockjs, vertx-httpclient

I am connection through Vertx eventbus (SockJS to my Java based backend. Everything work fine, However, I cannot find a way to send an initial message.

Is there a way to send back data when SockJS bridge receives SOCKET_CREATED to the sockjs browser side?

Thank you.

Comment: Client-Side [Documentation](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)

Comment: Ok,  thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from their documentation:

```
if (event.type() == SOCKET_CREATED || event.type() == SOCKET_CLOSED)
{
     //...
     vertx.eventBus().publish("fromServer", jmsg.toJSONString());
}
```

Your `event` instantiation may be different, but that would be how you check for the specific event and run code after it has occurred

Comment: That's great, but that's the easy part,

How do you accept it in the Javascript client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286251/4810042) , where I'm using EventBus.

Here is the Reference code

```
this.eventBus = new EventBus(this.URL);
this.eventBus.onopen = (e) => {
       this._opened = true;
        console.log("open connection");
        this.callHandlers('open', e);
        this.eventBus.publish("http://localhost:8082", "USER LOGIN INFO");

        this.eventBus.registerHandler("http://localhost:8081/pushNotification", function (error, message) {
           console.log(message.body);


        //$("<div title='Basic dialog'>Test   message</div>").dialog();

  });
}
this.eventBus.onclose = (e) => {
    this.callHandlers('close', e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Eventually I found a workaround using `onmessage` callback.

Comment: ok good...this one is different approach using EventBus which is using sockjs internally. :)