# SOCKJS client - Detect server is unreachable

Tags: javascript, websocket, vert.x, sockjs

I'm using vertxbus that internally built upon sockjs and I have a basic question.

When I call 'onopen' for the first time in order to establish a connection, How can I know that server is down?

At this point when I call 'onopen' and pass a callback function - if server is down the method is stuck and doesn't return at all.

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps `onerror` would help, as sockjs claims to mimic the `WebSockets API` - or maybe onclose with the onclose code being 1006 (as per WebSockets API that sockjs claims to mimic)

Comment: as far as I can tell and checked - onerror nor onclose are not triggered in this case.

Comment: well, so much for mimicking  WebSockets API :p

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something very basic...

Comment: perhaps some code in the question

Comment: setTimeout a failure callback and clearTimeout on it from the onopen() event.

Comment: dandavis - that is a workaround that I might do - but I was strongly under the impression that sockjs offers a builtin capability for this basic case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286251/4810042)  , where I'm using EventBus.

Here is the Reference code

```
 this.eventBus = new EventBus(this.URL);
    this.eventBus.onopen = (e) => {
           this._opened = true;
            console.log("open connection");
            this.callHandlers('open', e);
            this.eventBus.publish("http://localhost:8082", "USER LOGIN INFO");

            this.eventBus.registerHandler("http://localhost:8081/pushNotification", function (error, message) {
               console.log(message.body);


            //$("<div title='Basic dialog'>Test   message</div>").dialog();

      });
    }
    this.eventBus.onclose = (e) => {
        this.callHandlers('close', e);
      }
    }
```