# Vertx 3 - SockJS socket opening canceled

Tags: java, vert.x, sockjs, vertx-verticle

I created a new verticle that should response for HTTP requests and SockJS bridged events. Based on this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516328](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516328/) and vert.x manual https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sockjs I created this piece of code:

Java:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
        startHttpServer(startFuture);
        startSockJSHandler();
    }

    private void startHttpServer(Future<Void> startFuture) {
        HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions());
        server.requestHandler(req -> {
            System.out.println("[" + new Date().toString() + "] Request #" + ++requestCount);
            if (req.path().contains("http")) {
                req.response().putHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").end("req_num: " + requestCount);
            }
        }).listen(8080, ar -> startFuture.handle(ar.mapEmpty()));
    }

    private void startSockJSHandler() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        SockJSHandlerOptions sockJSOptions = new SockJSHandlerOptions().setHeartbeatInterval(2000);
        SockJSHandler sockJSHandler = SockJSHandler.create(vertx, sockJSOptions);
        BridgeOptions bridgeOptions = new BridgeOptions();
        bridgeOptions.addInboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*")).addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().setAddressRegex(".*"));
        sockJSHandler.bridge(bridgeOptions, be -> {
            System.out.println("BRIDGE EVENT: " + be.type().toString());
        });
        router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(sockJSHandler);
    }
```

JavaScript eventbus client:

```
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/eventbus/');

sock.onopen = function() {
  console.log('open');
  sock.send('test');
};

sock.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('message', e.data);
  sock.close();
};

sock.onclose = function() {
  console.log('close');
};
```

HTTP request/response works fine, but SockJS events not. In web browser 'Network' module I see only one SockJS request (http://localhost:8080/eventbus/info). 8 seconds in 'pending' status, and after this time the status is changed to 'closed' (method onclose() is called at the end).

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286251/4810042

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpServer` must delegate requests to the `Router`. Otherwise nothing happens. Usually, it is configured to delegate all requests to the `Router`.

```
server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
```

See [Basic Vert.x-Web concepts](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_basic_vert_x_web_concepts) in the docs.