# How to specify remote address for websocket connection in html

Tags: java, templates, websocket, vert.x

In [vertx example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/core/http/websockets/ws.html) websocket url hardcoded in html as localhost:

```
 socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/myapp");
```

Which is the correct, "production" way for specifying the remote address in html, especially in vertx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to Vert.x at all, but you can use `window.location.host` to get the current (page) host:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/myapp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on environment you can load websocket :

```
 if(location.origin.includes("localhost")){
       this.wsUrl = "http://localhost:8080/myapp";          
    }else{
      this.wsUrl = location.origin +"/myapp";
    }

   socket = new WebSocket(this.wsUrl);
```

you can use sockjs-client to open websocket : [sockjs-client](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)

Have a look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41286251/4810042) .
I hope this will help you :)